# Fluid not falling correctly on an obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've asked a [similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/fluid-is-floating-instead-of-falling) to this, but the answer for it (which worked back then) doesn't apply to this problem.

I've got a Fluid, a domain, and an plane that has been deformed from a cube into a ramp-thing:
[image]

The fluid seems to fall along the midpoint of the object's bounding box instead of the physical points: 
[image]

Here are my Obstacle settings:
[image]
[image]

And the fluid settings:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's quite simple - apply transforms (particulalry scale) for both obstacles (and normals won't behave crazy anymore). This was written in that answer although it wasn't there as important as here,

Comment: @MrZak That did not work.

Comment: @Josh Silveous, could it be that the simulation is cached/baked? and after applying transform it needs to be recalculated?

Comment: @m.ardito after applying the calculation i re-baked it, no changes.

Comment: from what I see in the file, it seems that the domain is a cube, but since the simulation cannot trespass the domain... it bounces back when domain (cube) limits are reached... the ramp is an obstacle, but it should be inside the domain (the cube)...

Comment: Re make every thing. I did create a new obticel and removed every thing exept the inflow and domain and it don't work

Comment: Did you try that ? Could you explain *what* didn't work when pointing that out ? Look at [this result](http://i.imgur.com/FucWS3a.gif) and compare it with your gif. At least they differ.

Comment: @m.ardito that was the problem but whenever I move the domain cube and apply the location it just resets it